# Array as fmu input

Tags: simulink, fmi

i'm trying to export a simulink model as fmu. It has some constant parameters and takes as input a vector of velocity. The problem is that the version 2.0 of fmi does not support this data structure.

I also tried the 3.0 version, but without success (In theory is supported by the standard).
What i want to do is to use this exported model in a framework named mosaik and use different parameters and array of velocities.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Which way do you use to export FMUs?

There is native FMI 3.0 support by Mathworks starting in R2023B.
This should have array support. Citing from https://de.mathworks.com/help/slcompiler/release-notes.html
"The following FMI 3.0 features are supported for an FMU in Simulink: ...    Vector and array support"
However this is not (yet?) documented on https://de.mathworks.com/help/slcompiler/gs/export-simulink-models-to-functional-mock-up-units.html
I do not have experience with this. Please check with the Mathworks support.

There are other solutions to export FMUs from Simulink, such as FMI-Kit https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMIKit-Simulink which support export of array variables for inputs and outputs.

With Mosaik you mean https://gitlab.com/mosaik/components/mosaik-fmi.  Does this support FMI 3.0?